# ActiveRecord : ordering the output of a where request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm trying to order the output of a where ActiveRecord query :

```
result = Class.where('a = ? AND b = ?', params[:a], params[:b])
```

I tried chaining `order` both before and after without succeeding, what am I missing ?

```
#Not working, the order is not modified compared to previous line
result = Class.where('a = ? AND b = ?', params[:a], params[:b]).order('c DESC')
```

Comment: can u post me a sample set of data. The query looks fine to me.

Comment: Make sure you don't have `default scope` with `order` defined in the model.

Comment: Congrats, I do. Do I need to delete it, or can I overwrite this behavior locally ? (you should make an answer ! )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to `unscope` the model, something like

```
result = Class.unscoped.where('a = ? AND b = ?', params[:a], params[:b]).order('c DESC')
```

Or delete the default scope if it is not used elsewhere